# How to search words from android app to any website(prize bond)?

Tags: java, android, web, jsoup, screen-scraping

I am making prize bond app in android. In which user can add their prize bond numbers and they will be notified automatically through sms on mobile if they won any prize. 
There is no api of prize bond. This is the website from which I want to get data.

**https://www.prizebond.net/**

All I want when user add prize bond numbers in app. in the background i just search that numbers in the site and get the data through web scraping using jsoup.

Is it possible?(I search a lot but didn't get the solution and I am new to android development.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You won't find a solution online to something that specific. Do research on how to pull data from web pages. One easy way I can suggest is pay attention to the HTML tags used for the data you want, and search only through the relevant tags. That will cut down on junk data you might grab searching through an entire document.

Comment: I know how to grab data. For example, i have a text field in app and when user click the search button in my app, in the background i go to **google.com** search that words and display that data (using web scraping)to user. 

How to search in google in this example? that's my question.

Comment: jsoup should have everything you need then. It's up to you to write specific code to deal with the exact data you're trying to extract. Your question is quite broad right now. I suggest starting small, grabbing some easy data, an HTML header <h1> even, and pulling it to your program. Work up from there. You'll need to get very friendly with the jsoup API. The only way to do that is to just start using it.